# How to create a file with a custom file type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, mobile, file-upload

I'm creating a mobile app, and I want user to enter some details in text fields, and the results of those text fields I'm storing in a variable. At the end, I have a variable which consists of a large string. Then I want to be able to create a file, with a custom type, and store the value of that variable inside this file. Simply the file should consists of that text. So it will be a text file, only I will specify the extension. Then I will send that file to a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [***Blob***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) for this, but it won't be "saved" to the client's device. The *Blob* can then be submitted to the server using an *XMLHttpRequest*

```
//                 bytes      ,  mime
var b = new Blob(['text data'], 'text/plain');

// make it easy to submit or just submit it directly
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fileParam', b, 'file_name.txt');

// assuming XMLHttpRequest xhr
xhr.send(fd);
```

If *FormData* is not available for the device, then you can send the blob directly. Adding a *FormData* makes the server side easier as it is the same as if you submitted a `<form>` with some `<input>`.